# How to handle conflicting dependencies in Java

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, classloader, dependency-management

In my Java project I have two external dependencies, A and B. I have these as JAR files on my build path. Both project A and B have the external dependency project C. However they rely on different versions of C. If I use the version that's compatible with A, then B breaks, and vice versa.

How to handle this?

Comment: Sounds interesting, my solution to this kind of problem is to exclude one of the conflict dependencies. You may try to exclude both of them and include one make compatibility with both A and B. That one may be found between the two conflict versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to dependency hell.

Three approaches:

1. If at least one of the projects A and B is yours, you can try to change the code to reach compatibility with the desired version of C. Ideally, you can update both A and B to the latest stable version of C and "repair" the code to make it work.
2. If both A and B are external projects, you might experiment with different versions of A and B because they probably rely on different versions of C. Maybe you'll find a combination that works with the same C.
3. Construct a *shaded* jar with the Maven shade plugin. Here, you modify the package names of one version of C to make it independent of the other version.